# Create an array of custom Object to fill it and take his content to fill a UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have a Class called Product that contains some propeties, I wanna make that my class will be the base for an list of Product called Products. And this list can access in a UITableView to fill it with the content of Products.

Also, the content of each product will be filled by a web service.

My code is:

```
@interface Product : NSObject
{
    int identifier;
    NSString* title;
    NSString* quantity;
    float price;
    UIImage* image;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) int identifier;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* quantity;
@property (nonatomic, assign) float price;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *image;


-(id)initWithProduct:(int) identifier withTitle:(NSString*)title numberUses:(NSString*)uses withPrice:(float)price withImage:(UIImage*)image;


@end
```

With his .m

```
@implementation Product
@synthesize identifier = _identifier;
@synthesize title = _title;
@synthesize price = _price;
@synthesize quantity = _quantity;
@synthesize image = _image;

- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"article dealloc \n");
    [self.title release];
    [self.quantity release];
    [self.image release];

    [super dealloc];
}
- (id)init {

    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        self.title     = [[[NSMutableString alloc] init] autorelease];
        self.identifier  = 0;
        self.price   = 45.0;
        self.quantity   = [[[NSMutableString alloc] init] autorelease];
        self.image    = [[[UIImage alloc] init] autorelease];

    }
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithProduct:(int) inIdentifier withTitle:(NSString*)inTitle numberUses:(NSString*)inQuantity withPrice:(float)inPrice withImage:(UIImage*)inImage
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        if (title!= nil) {
            self.title = inTitle;
        }
        if (quantity!= nil) {
            self.quantity = inTitle;
        }
        if (image!= nil) {
            self.title = inTitle;
        }
        self.price = inPrice;
        self.identifier = inIdentifier;
    }
    return self;
}    
@end
```

My UITableView header is:

```
@interface TableView : UIViewController
<   UITableViewDataSource
,   UITableViewDelegate
>{
    NSMutableArray *products;
}
```

in the m. I have:

**EDIT**
Now the Title of my cell is shows as (null)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        products = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [products addObject:[[Product alloc] initWithProduct:1 withTitle:@"df" numberUses:@"dsf" withPrice:12.3 withImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_invite"]]];
    [products addObject:[[Product alloc] initWithProduct:1 withTitle:@"2" numberUses:@"dsf" withPrice:12.3 withImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_invite"]]];
    [products addObject:[[Product alloc] initWithProduct:1 withTitle:@"4" numberUses:@"dsf" withPrice:12.3 withImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_invite"]]];
    [products addObject:[[Product alloc] initWithProduct:1 withTitle:@"4" numberUses:@"dsf" withPrice:12.3 withImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_invite"]]];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
Controller *cell = (Controller*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil)
            {
                NSString* nameNib = UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad == UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() ? @"Controller" : @"ControllerIph";
                NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nameNib owner:self options:nil];
                cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
            }
  Product* obj = [products objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.title.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", obj.title];
   return cell;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

                return 4;
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see an initWithChip method in your Product implementation file

Comment: When the table is load. [__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 4 beyond bounds [0 .. 3]'

Comment: Can you show the implementation of `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`?

Comment: I just deleted my comments and made them into an answer so that I have more space to elaborate. Sorry for the confusion :-)

Comment: Edited my answer why you see "(null)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an answer to your question, but a few comments regarding your code:

- You have 4 memory leaks when you add the 4 new instances of `Product` to your array. The array retains the objects you add to it, so you should `autorelease` the `Product` instances when you add them.
- In `dealloc` you should say `self.title = nil` instead of `[self.title release]`. Although your version works, it leaves you with instance variables that contain references to deallocated objects (= dangling pointers). Because this happens in `dealloc` and the `Product` object is going away soon, it won't hurt you now, but you *will* get bitten at some point in the future if you keep to this style.
- You don't need to declare the instance variables, and you don't need to synthesize the properties. The compiler does all this for you.
- In `initWithProduct` you must not check things like `if (title!= nil)` - just say `self.title = inTitle` straightaway. After all, `initWithProduct` is an initializer just like `init`, so `title` cannot contain anything at this point.

Hope this helps.

---

EDIT

Actually, the last point is probably why you see "(null)" for the title of your cells. Your check `if (title!= nil)` is never true because the instance variable `title` is `nil` during the initializer, so the assignment `self.title = inTitle` never happens.

Comment: Thanks! :) Is pretty cool your help!
Now, is correct my way of create the array of Products? It can help me if I wanna fill my array of objects with data of the web?

Comment: @lightless07 The `Product` class certainly won't give you any trouble, after all it's just a simple data class. As for filling the array, well, I would suggest that you create a separate class that interacts with your web service and creates `Product` instances. Your controller can then obtain the `Product` instances from that other class. I don't have experience with web services, though, so I can't give you any hints that are more specific than this.

Answer (score 2):

In `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` you do not initialize cells for your TableView. Add the below code to this method before the code that you already have

```
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell Identifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell;
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
```

and make sure you `return cell;` at the end of that method

Also make sure you implement the rest of the necessary TableView delegate methods:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

Comment: Can you help me with the titles? My code don't show me correctly the content of the array :(

Comment: look at @herzbube 's answer